# Change directory and execute lua file in one command in Putty

Tags: putty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6S0F.jpg)

Hi all,

I am trying to read temperature for a device using putty. I trying to run a Lua file in putty in one line of command.

Exp: File to run : heater_monitor.lua Path: media/umass-32/heater_monitor.lua

Can I run the file (heater_monitor.lua) as follows in the path?:

cd /media/umass-32 && heater_monitor.lua

Media

|  ___umass-sim-32 (subfolder)
|     |___heater_monitor.lua
|     |
|

I wanted to run the .lua file in one single line of command as such
/media/umass-sim-32/heater_monitor.lua

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
WJ

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have two questions here; can you cd to a directory and run a command as the first and can you give a fully qualified command as the second. Both are possible and both examples you give are correct. If you're at a shell prompt then the use of PuTTY or any other ssh client or terminal emulator is not relevant.

Comment: @doneal24 I typed the following at the shell prompt  "cd /media/umass-32 && heater_monitor.lua" It did not work. I am trying to avoid to type "ls, cd--> for toplevel folder and cd --> for subfolder

Comment: Define "did not work". Please edit your question with the command you used and the exact error messages you received.